# Some symbols load (display) issue when converting MathML to LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, pdftex, typography, mathml

I'm using [David Carlisle's stylesheet](https://github.com/davidcarlisle/web-xslt/tree/master/pmml2tex) to convert `MathML` to `LaTeX`. The stylesheet does a phenomenal job for converting even very complex MathML into `LaTeX`. But I'm having trouble displaying following two symbols correctly:

1. `degree`
2. `approximately equal to`

I tried adding following two entries into his `pmml-new.sty` file which sets up a mechanism to declare behaviour for unicode characters but leaves most undefined. But I'm getting different results (displays). **Question**: How I can make the display right?

**Remark**: I'm using `MikTeX` on `Windows 10`

**Entries that I added to pmml-new.sty file**:

```
......
\@namedef{uc176}{\circ}
\@namedef{uc8776}{\asymp}
```

**Examples**

`\@namedef{uc176}{\circ}` displays `degree` in the text [image] as [image].

And `\@namedef{uc8776}{\asymp}` displays `approximately equal to` in the text [image] as [image]

Comment: After reading the first sentence, somehow I knew the second sentence was going to start with "But" :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Agreed. Actually my second sentence should have been: `But (to my own fault) I'm having trouble.....` - as it turned out (from your solution below) that indeed was the case. Your suggestion/solution worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\circ` is a centred circle for degree you want `^{\circ}` and you want`\approx` for U+2248.

In general these days it might be easier to use `pmml-new` but with a TeX setup using luatex or xetex and `unicode-math` then the majority of math related unicode characters could be just sent straight through to TeX and would do the right thing automatically.